# Why my Xcode without 'using local signing assets' option

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing

When I try to export a IPA file and choose '**save for Ad Hoc Deployment**' option, next Xcode want me to select a Development Team to use for provisioning, so I should to choose 'use local signing assets' option

But I found it did **not** have '**use local signing assets**' option.

Help me deal with this question.

Comment: Do you have provisoning profile and certificates on your Mac?

Comment: yes I have them on my Mac

Comment: Go to project settings -> General

In team option, choose the option of "Personal team" and then you will get a prompt of Fix issues. Click on that. Hope that will fix the problem.

Comment: but I have not account ,this project is using other people's account, I only have their profile and certificate, it

Answer (score 0):

I run to the same issue and it was caused by expired team membership.

So make sure that you are member of development team with **not expired** membership. Then you will be able to choose "**use local signing assets**" from combobox.